# How to unhide just the last previous hidden objects/mesh?

Tags: interface

Is it possible rather than unhide everything , i want to unhide just the last hidden element ?

Here's the case :  i work on complex mesh. i hide the other part and work on current mesh, but sometime i want to go detailing further, so i hide again some faces , then do the work here, then i just want to go back to unhide just the last one, because if i use 'unhide' it will unhide all object , so i have to repeat the process of my hidden object setup again. moving to other layer can be to much for every single simple task.

Thaks

Comment: I don't think you can unhide the last hidden element. I guess you know that you can hide everything but the selection with shift H?

Comment: THanks, yes, i know that shift H. But the situation is when you already hide most of your scene to work /focus on your element . But sometimes in the middle of  my work , there's some part of active mesh which covering my view, even i already in wireframe mode and trying to get best view of it but still not making me happy so i  want to hide temporarily some faces, just for doing one or two command then go back the previous hidden setup, without have to go back all the way to unhide all objects.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for .. but you could organise your mesh into vertex groups, and use Mask modifiers to hide/unhide those groups.

Answer (score 1):

If it will help anybody, using <kbd>/</kbd> fit what I needed in this same situation, toggles on and off with repeat presses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd>, that will unhide hidden objects.